# D3100 Dell docking station

Tags: linux, drivers

So I got my Fedora 22 as I finally decided to switch from Fedora 20 ( been using it forever, found it kinda hard to detach )

The problem is that I bought my new docking station for multiple monitors and it simply does not work.
There is one display port on it and two HDMI ports for monitors and a bunch of USB 3.0 ports.

I know there are issues with display ports but I am not even using it all the monitors go over HDMI and the docking station is connected to the laptop via USB 3.0 as well

I ve looked online for the drivers with no luck also for some people it seams to work on Ubuntu 15.04.

Could anybody help me out.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The drivers are available for Ubuntu at displaylink.org here:

http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php

But people have had to modify the installation scripts depending on their setup/distro with mixed success.  For now, DisplayLink are only focusing on Ubuntu.

There is a pretty good thread on the D3100 if you scroll down near the end here (starting from 8/4/15, this is recent stuff):

http://www.displaylink.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-1748.html

Comment: Okay so I go the displaylink drivers for ubuntu, some people have managed to get it work on Fedora 22 so I looked at how they modified the installation script and I used that, the installation seams to have worked once and once alone and I could detect my other monitors but I could not enable them at all so I tried reinstalling and after the reinstallation I could no longer even see the monitors in system settings. now I can not even start the displaylink service with systemctl, log files state the following:

Comment: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/lib/displaylink/DisplayLinkManager: No such file or directory

Comment: So what I did was copy DisplayLinkManager to /usr/lib/displaylink and gave it the 0755 permissions as the installation script would do. But I still keep getting the same error message even though the file is there.

Comment: OMG so finally after I had to do everything manually prior to the installation and than more work after I managed to get it to work and recognize my other monitor, but now I got a different problem. Even though I can see the other monitor I can not enable it in system settings and I haven't got a clue why, could you help me out figure it out.

Comment: I don't have the D3100 personally, so beyond the links above there's not much I can do.  You might try reading through the installation shell script and see if it does anything to enable it - maybe adding something to X11 config?

Comment: Okay so after a couple of reboots and reinstalltions I managed to get it to work I posted a solution on Linux.org as I can post links there for anyone else who might have problems.